# Preload of images to prevent flickering using the picture tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, responsive-design, preload

In my code I have a tag picture, and I change its content in order to load an other image. But I noticed flickering  .  Here my toy code.

```js
setTimeout(replaceImage,3000);

function replaceImage(){
let pictureNode = document.getElementById('picture-carousel');

let markup = `
               <source media="(min-width:50em)" srcset="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/debris2_blue.png">
                
                  <source media="(min-width:25em)" srcset="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/debris2_brown.png"> 
                  <source  srcset="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/debris3_blue.png"> 
                  <img src='http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/debris2_blue.png' title='Bla bla' alt='bla bla'>
`

pictureNode.innerHTML = markup;
}
```

```html
<div>
<picture id='picture-carousel'>
                  <source media="(min-width:50em)" srcset="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blend.png">
                
                  <source media="(min-width:25em)" srcset="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blue.png"> 
                  <source  srcset="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_brown.png"> 
                  <img src='http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blend.png' title='Bla bla' alt='bla bla'> <!--  fallback -->
               </picture>
               </div>
```

I know that to tacke flickering for images I can preload the images like that:

```js
function loadImage(){
var img = new Image(),
x=document.getElementById('myImg');
img.onload=function(){
  x.src = img.src;
}

img.src ='http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back03.jpg'; //  this is the new url img to load';
}
```

```html
<img src='http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back02.jpg' id='myImg'>

<button onclick='loadImage();'>Load new Image</button>
```

How could I preload image when I'm using the picture tag rather than the img tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct your `<picture>` element in the form of data. That way we can build a function that takes in the data and builds the element up piece by piece.

When doing this, we can check the `media` value for each individual `<source>` tag. With that value we can run [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to determine if the media query on the element matches the current view. For example, you can check if `min-width: 50em` is currently true or not.

With that knowledge you can determine which image to preload. You only have to load the image that matches the media query.

Check the example below, it does the processes describes above.
Please reach out if you have any question.

```js
const pictureData = [
  {
    tag: 'source',
    attributes: {
      media: '(min-width: 50em)',
      srcset: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/debris2_blue.png'
    }
  },
  {
    tag: 'source',
    attributes: {
      media: '(min-width: 25em)',
      srcset: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/debris2_brown.png'
    }
  },
  {
    tag: 'source',
    attributes: {
      srcset: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/debris3_blue.png'
    }
  },
  {
    tag: 'img',
    attributes: {
      src: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/debris2_blue.png',
      title: 'Bla bla',
      alt: 'bla bla'
    }
  }
];

/**
 * Loads an image and returns a promise.
 * The promise will resolve on the load event of the image.
 */
const preloadImage = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.onload = () => resolve();
  image.onerror = error => reject(error);
  image.src = url;
})

/**
 * Takes in an object of pictureData.
 * It then creates a <picture> element and the children specified in the object.
 * Whenever a tag is source, it will use the media value, if present,
 * to detect if the image is elligable to be loaded. 
 * If so it will preload the image and resolve the promise after it has been loaded.
 */
const buildPicture = async pictureData => {
  const picture = document.createElement('picture');
  let imageToPreload = null;

  // Loop through all the data and start constructing.
  for (const { tag, attributes } of pictureData) {
    const child = document.createElement(tag);
    
    if (imageToPreload === null) {
      // Check source tags for media queries.
      if (tag === 'source') {
        const { media, srcset } = attributes;
        
        // If there is a media query, check it.
        if (!media) {
          const { matches } = window.matchMedia(media);

          // If the query matches, use this as the image.
          if (matches === true) {
            imageToPreload = srcset;
          }

        // No media query found.
        } else {
          imageToPreload = srcset;
        }
      }

      // If no match has been found yet, just load the image.
      if (tag === 'img') {
        const { src } = attributes;
        imageToPreload = src;
      }
    }
    
    // Set all the properties and values of the attributes.
    for (const [ property, value ] of Object.entries(attributes)) {
      child.setAttribute(property, value);
    }

    picture.append(child);
  }

  if (imageToPreload !== null) {
    try {
      await preloadImage(imageToPreload);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return picture;
};

setTimeout(async () => {
  const currentPicture = document.getElementById('picture-carousel');
  const picture = await buildPicture(pictureData);
  currentPicture.replaceWith(picture);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<picture id='picture-carousel'>
  <source media="(min-width:50em)" srcset="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blend.png">
  <source media="(min-width:25em)" srcset="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blue.png">
  <source srcset="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_brown.png">
  <img src='http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blend.png' title='Bla bla' alt='bla bla'>
  <!--  fallback -->
</picture>
```

Comment: This way since you check with javascript which media query is triggered using the picture tag becomes useless and I could directly use only the img tag

Comment: Sure, you could do it solely with JavaScript. But you'll lose the ability to change image when the screen size changes.

Comment: Yes, or I should have a listener on the change event for each media query size